# Using smart phone as bootbale external media

Tags: external-hard-drive, bootable-media, smartphone

is it possible to turn a smart phone (while retaining its core functionality as a smart phone in some way) into a bootable media so that you can use it to do the heavy lifting on a lower spec laptop, or tablet, etc? I know I can do this with an external Hard drive- but it would be cool to do it with a phone.

Comment: What would be the point, really? You would't be doing any 'heavy lifting' you'd be using it as a boot drive over USB, which is going to be a whole lot slower than booting off the internal drive.

Comment: To build on @user1686's answer below, the easiest way to increase performance on a lower spec PC is to install an SSD and install Linux _(it's a night and day difference between Windows, which is resource hungry by default; as such, it performs poorly on lower-spec PCs)_.  Upgrading the RAM to at least 8GB, preferably 16GB, would also help, but the first two will provide the biggest performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no.

First, modern smartphones do not provide the USB "Mass Storage" protocol anymore, since it needs exclusive access – either the computer can access the flash memory *or* the phone's OS can access it, but not both at the same time.

(Older phones *did* support this protocol, and they'd show up exactly like a USB stick or a like an SD-card reader – but you always needed to go into a special "storage only" mode that shuts down the phone's OS.)

Second, you won't be able to use the phone's CPU nor GPU nor RAM. 'Bootable external media' can *only* provide storage, it **will not** allow the phone to do any "heavy lifting". So there's nothing you'd gain from using a phone here – you might as well just buy a good USB 3.0 flashdrive, or one of those "portable SSDs".

(There is no USB protocol that'd let the host use the attached device as its main CPU – not that it could; the phone's Arm-architecture CPU cannot run your x86-architecture OS anyway.)

Finally, internal storage connectors are always faster than USB (and the "Mass Storage" protocol is slow in itself, too). The "low-spec" computer might not even have a USB 3.0 port – but it'll still have a SATA port where you can attach a cheap SSD instead.